# Thymeleaf не видит поле объекта

Tags: thymeleaf

Вот мой объект:

```
public class Ingredient {
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private double quantity;

    private UnitOfMeasurement unit;
}
```

А вот что видит Thymeleaf:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему он не видит поле unit?

Comment: Ну, если оно не выводится в подсказках, то это ещё не значит, что Thymeleaf его вовсе не видит. Попробуйте фактически протестировать. Например, в какой-нибудь элемент засунуть значение этого поля.